# ios phonegap number keypad

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, keypad

I wrote input field as `type="number"`.
It shows  digits and some special characters like `(`, `)`,etc keypad on iphone.

But if I click `(` , then it automatically removes it and shows only numbers.

I have to make app showing number keypad and allow to input not only digits but also some special characters like `(`, `)`, `white-space`,`'`,`"`, etc.
I hope you can help me.

PS. I'm using cordova2.8.1

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `<input>` tag with type number you can use **Sencha touch xtype: numberfield** in following way, it would give result as u expect:

```
  {
    xtype: 'numberfield',
    label: 'Phone Number',
    labelAlign:'top',
    component: {
      xtype: 'input',
      type: 'tel'
    },
  },
```